# Youtube scroll bar styling

Tags: css

Does anybody knows how Youtube has made this custom scrollbar?

[image]

Is new --web-kit is used or some plugin?

Comment: Why don't inspect html code ? Also you can find [here](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_custom_scrollbar.asp) doc for custom scrollbar

Comment: Well doen, but I think it is in javascript

Comment: Yes but we can access to html content: http://prntscr.com/1u7dzko

Answer (score 1):

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
      width: 15px; // scrollbar width
}
    
::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
 background: red; 
}
 
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: blue; 
}
```

Comment: The problem is that it shows on hover

Comment: Edited please check it.

Comment: Works for me. 

`
::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 7px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background: transparent;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  border-radius: 20px;
}
`

Answer (score 0):

This is some `-webkit-scrollbar` CSS properties.

You will find the necessary documentaiton [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::-webkit-scrollbar#css_scrollbar_selectors).

Comment: you can find here the youtube sidebar scrolling style.

https://codepen.io/kqwesi/pen/jOPvaPg

https://codepen.io/brandonwingerair/pen/EdPPeX

Comment: It is nice documetnation, but, you will see it will appear in hover, I dont find this all in documentation